# Values are not fetching in my WordPress website?

Tags: php, wordpress, phpmyadmin

Values are not fetching in my WordPress website? This is the code, tell me the write way to fetch value from data base......Values are not fetching in my WordPress website? This is the code, tell me the write way to fetch value from data base......

```
<?php 
        $sql2= "SELECT seat_per_day from `wps_reservation_setting` " ;
        $Data1 = mysql_query($sql2);

        $row2 = mysql_fetch_array($Data1);

        for($i = 1 ;$i <= $row2['seat_per_day'] ;$i++ )
        { 
        ?>
        <option value="<?php print $i; ?>"><?php print $i; ?></option>

        <?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In wordpress fetch data from database as following

```
  global $wpdb;
  $table_set = $wpdb->prefix . 'reservation_setting';
    $fivesdrafts = $wpdb->get_results( 
        "
        SELECT seat_per_day 
        FROM $table_set
        "
    );

    foreach ( $fivesdrafts as $fivesdraft ) 
    {
        echo $fivesdraft->seat_per_day;
    }
```

Comment: How I can add these values on Select, As I given above
its good and fetching But I need data in Select Option